# how to use delete method in route in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

## I want to use delete route in my laravel project.

like and want to send route from href of a anchor tag.
is it possible to use delete method in route from "href" of anchor tag

```
 Route::delete('/news/{id}', 'NewsController@destroy');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use anchor tag with href to send the request to delete. You need a form todo so. With a method *DELETE* since in form we have only get and post so create a hidden field with name _method and value **DELETE** 
Create form similar to this :

```
<form action="news/id" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{csrf_token}}" >
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" >
<input type="submit" value="delete " >
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::resource('/news/{id}', 'NewsController@destroy');
```

and then select post, put, delete ...

[image]

Comment: in the case, i need to use route::delete();   i want to give url from a <a href="{{url('admin/news/delete',$item->id)}}">Delete</a></td>      not working.

Comment: What is the interface in your visual?