# Laravel 5.4 using <a> for POST method

Tags: php, laravel

Before anyone points that is a duplicate I have checked these questions - [laravel 5.4 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 251)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753514/laravel-5-4-methodnotallowedhttpexception-in-routecollection-php-line-251), [(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237165/1-1-methodnotallowedhttpexception) among others.

My problem is that I have done all of the solutions to all of the above posted questions and none have solved my issue.

**ProfileController**

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Auth;


class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function show($name) {

        $user = User::whereName($name)->first();
        if ($user) {

            // User exists
            return view('profile')->withUser($user);
        } else {
            dd($user);
        }

    }


    public function destroy($id){          


        DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('/'); 
        }


}
```

**profile.blade**

```
      <ul class="profile-hero-header-menu">

    <li><a class="button primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#160;Request Changes</a></li>
    <li><a class="button success" href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#160;Contact Support</a></li>
      <form action="/profile/{id}/delete" method="POST">
      {{ csrf_field() }} 
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <li><a class="button alert" href="{{ route('profile.destroy', auth()->user()->id) }}" name="DELETE"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#160;Close Account</a></li>
   </form>
  </ul>
```

**web**

```
Route::delete('/profile/{id}/delete', 'ProfileController@destroy')->name('profile.destroy')->middleware('auth');
```

On user click "Close Account" throws an exception -[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use delete method in route in laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621332/how-to-use-delete-method-in-route-in-laravel-5-2)

Comment: What is the url when u click the delete??

Comment: Try to change your `<a href` in your form to a `button` that actually submits/POSTs the form.

Comment: Also watch for valid HTML, `form`, `li`, `/form`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DELETE` method works as a POST with forms but you are using `<a>` which is a `GET`

So change this

```
<li><a class="button primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#160;Request Changes</a></li>
    <li><a class="button success" href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#160;Contact Support</a></li>
      <form action="/profile/{id}/delete" method="POST">
      {{ csrf_field() }} 
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <li><a class="button alert" href="{{ route('profile.destroy', auth()->user()->id) }}" name="DELETE"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#160;Close Account</a></li>
   </form>
```

to This

```
<li><a class="button primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#160;Request Changes</a></li>
    <li><a class="button success" href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#160;Contact Support</a></li>
      <form action="/profile/{id}/delete" method="POST">
      {{ csrf_field() }} 
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <li><button class="button alert" type="submit" name="DELETE"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#160;Close Account</button></li>
   </form>
```

So change change your `<a>` to this

```
 <button class="button alert" type="submit" name="DELETE"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></button>
```

Comment: You could use blade helper `{{method_field()}}` instead of writing whole hidden input in HTML. [source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are requesting to a wrong endpoint, so try with using **route** helper and pass the parameter

```
<form action="{{route('profile.destroy',auth()->user->id)}}" method="POST">
```